# redis cluster mget return guarantee order?

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I'm using the redis cluster environment If I look up using the mget command, do I guarantee that the returned values will come out in order?

I looked for various documents, but I couldn't find them

Thank you. Have a nice day